# Is it possible to use the evtree package in R for panel data / over multiple years?

Tags: r, panel-data, evolutionary-algorithm, cart-analysis

I would like to know, if it is possible to use evtree over multiple years?

I have an unbalanced panel data set (8 years), with two groups based on a (binary) dependent variable (dv). For every year, the dv-value for each observation can be either 0 or 1, and thus constitutes group membership. Also, I have multiple predictor variables (pv), where their influence on dv might change over time.

Evtree generally seems the correct approach for me (at least for a single year). My goal is to train the evtree model over multiple periods (to capture possible temporal effects) in order to classify the two groups as good as possible.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a methods question rather than a coding one and, so, better suited to Cross Validated than Stack Overflow. FWIW, though, one approach might be to create features representing your ideas about possible temporal effects (e.g., membership in previous period) and include those in an analysis of the pooled data.

Comment: @ulfelder: Thanks. A temporal change might be, that predictor variables are not equally important over time. So, setting up a model over just one year (period) might lead to unstable results (prediction) in the holdout sample. In that case a multiple year approach might be more appropriate? I'm unsure on how to pool the data, because then dependent variable for each observation could take both values [0,1] simultaneously, which is not possible. My goal is to have a stable, generalizable model.